# typescript and properties iteraction

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm working on an Angular 2 application. I have the following object definition:

```
export class MyFilter {

  public officeId: string;

  public year: number;

  pageNumber: number;

  pageSize: number;

  public constructor() {
    this.pageSize=10;
    this.pageNumber=10;
    this.year=2014;
    this.officeId='abc';
  }
```

}

I need to iterate over its properties through a for cycle like:

```
let bean=new MyFilter();

for (const p in bean) {
  if (bean.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
  console.log(p + ': ' + bean[p]);
  }
}
```

Note that i simplified the code to focus on problem. How can i iterate over its properties in typescript? The code that i wrote does not write anything.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to have any problem: https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/d6revm35/

Comment: you're right, thank you. Probably it was a transpiler problem. I run again the code and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let a=new MyFilter();
Object.keys(MyFilter).forEach((property) => {
console.log(a[property]);
});
```